# Can you debug dsPIC33F series with PicKit 2?

Tags: pickit

According to Pickit 2 readme it should be able to program it, but the dsPIC datasheet is not clear on debugging. Anyone had experiences with dsPIC33 and pickit 2?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the device. If you're using Windows MPLAB, select the device and you should get a dialog that indicates whether there is full programming and emulation support for the particular device and development hardware (green lights). You don't need a PICkit 2 on the computer to see this, BTW. For some  combinations you'll get a yellow indicator which highlights some kind of limitation(s).

[image]

As you can see here, the **dsPIC33FJ64GP710A** is not supported by PICkit 2.

Answer (score 0):

If it can programme it, it can debug it. MPLAB will tell you if the PICkit 2 is suitable if you select the device you want to use.